# How to avoid Page 404 Error on my first app

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I am following this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48xeeo5Vnk

Here is my code for views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>This is our blog</h1>')

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>This is our About Page</h1>')

def next(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>This is our next Page</h1>')
```

This is my App urls page code

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    path('next/', views.next, name='blog-NEXT'),
]
```

This is my main project URL code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('firstapp', include('firstapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Now when I try this with only single view i.e default page '', it works alone, with no more pages mentioned in code, however when I add more views it gives me a 404 page error. I believe the code is fine and it shoud work, but somehow it chose not to.

Tried different browser, tried forums but nothing.

Here is the error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/firstapp/

Using the URLconf defined in first.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    firstapp [name='blog-home']
    firstapp about/ [name='blog-about']
    firstapp next/ [name='blog-NEXT']
    admin/

The current path, firstapp/, didn't match any of these.
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: remove firstapp from path('firstapp', include('firstapp.urls')), to see home page or you put '/' after firstapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do below changes
from:

```
path('firstapp', include('firstapp.urls')),
```

to:

```
path('firstapp/', include('firstapp.urls')),
```